# How to solve a cryptarithm with multiple conditions

Tags: arithmetic, cryptarithm

I'm trying to solve a cryptarithm that must meet all of the following conditions:

> **one** + **one** = **two**
>
> **seven** is prime
>
> **nine** is a perfect square

More specifically, i'm trying to find the following:

> one =
>
> two =
>
> seven =
>
> nine =

Firstly, can someone explain the first condition (**one** + **one** = **two**) and how it fits in with the other conditons? Is this a sort of cryptarithm within a cryptarithm that must also stay true to the other conditions?

Secondly, what approach should I take to logically deduct the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, one is meant to assume that each of the letters o, n, e, t, w, s, v, i stands for a digit (maybe even a different digit) so **one** is a 3-digit number and so on. Now you make a lot of deductions along the lines of these:

The 1st condition tells you $o\le5$, and $o$ is even. The 2nd condition tells you $n$ is $1$, $3$, $7$, or $9$. The 3rd condition tells you $e$ is $1$, $4$, $5$, $6$, or $9$.

Collect enough of these bits of information and you have a chance of figuring out what each letter stands for.